# What does “Gentleman jockey wins the Derby” mean?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In the movie *The Thomas Crown Affair* there is the following dialog:

> I'm just an amateur.
>   Beginner's luck, huh? **Gentleman jockey wins the Derby**.
>   Something like that.

The expression ***"Gentleman jockey"*** is not available in the more common  online [dictionaries](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&ei=5sghWdHSM4aiU5rgmHg&q=gentleman%20jockey%20definition%20&oq=gentleman%20jockey%20definition%20&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...8797.11255.0.11450.13.13.0.0.0.0.158.1343.4j8.12.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.11.1258...35i39k1j0i19k1j0i22i30i19k1j0i22i30k1.KUfp7iQpUE8), so
what does "Gentleman jockey wins the Derby" mean here and in what contexts could I use it?

Comment: Please **include the [research](https://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/5039/)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](https://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2573/) are off-topic.

Comment: ***Gentleman jockey*** means amateur rider. And ***Derby*** is related to horseraces.

Comment: @NVZ - the definition is not readily available in dictionaries. I think the question makes sense.

Comment: A gentleman jockey is not a professional jockey -- he does not get paid, and he usually is from the upper classes.  See [here](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/04/04/sport/sam-waley-cohen-grand-national-horse-racing/)

Comment: @Josh I found the definition instantly on Google, the same one you posted, and other.

Comment: @NVZ - apparently the only available online, I guess a user may rightly ask about its meaning and usage.

Comment: @Josh Sure, they may ask. But they could also include the research that they have done. :)

Comment: @NVZ Anything, anything can be found on Google.  The fact that an answer can be put together from info on Google is not enough to make it answerable using "commonly available references."   In this case, yes, a quick Google yields the answer, and the question showed zero research, which is why I posted a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @ab2 My thoughts exactly. Also, my comment was first. ;)

Comment: @ab2 - yes, and given tha no dictionary provides a definition, what does "general reference" refer to in this case? Btw, why is an amateur player called Gentleman jokey?

Comment: @Josh This may be better discussed on meta, but my presonal rule of thumb is if a simple google of a word or phrase does not give an answer in the first google page, then it is fine to ask the question and give a brief summary of the failed googling.  Skillful googling or prolonged googling is not required, but mark-one mod-zero googling is, IMO.

Comment: @Josh because only gentlemen could afford to be a jockey for no pay (and possibly at great expense) or to do anything for no pay (and possibly at great expense), e.g., "gentleman farmer".  Possibly there is a question here in how the word "gentleman" has evolved.  I read a newspaper story several years ago in which a witness was quoted as saying something like: "This gentleman grabbed the jewelery on the counter and ran out the door."

Comment: @ab2 - it is easier to CV than to give an answer, but thanks for seeing  the potential for the question.

Comment: The expression ***"I'm just an amateur"*** is also absent from dictionaries. That's because is this not an idiomatic expression. It is a sentence, and one that means just exactly what all its individual pieces mean separately. You have to look up its pieces. This is not a candidate for reopening.

Comment: @tchrist - the question here is about meaning and usage of "Gentleman jokey" which does exist and is used in specific contexts. What's off-topic about asking this question? Why should a user not ask? How can one be sure about its meaning and usage if they can't find reference which is generally considered reliable. I understand it may sound too easy for you, but there are less knowledgable users around (me included).

Comment: @Josh Maybe it is about that, but if so neither the title nor the body says that. We do expect folks to look stuff up first.

Comment: @tchrist - I edited the question and added links to the available reference to "gentleman jokey"   in Google. It is for us to understand how to help OP.

Comment: @Josh you and your typos.... it's joCKEY!

Comment: @Josh a joke, is not the same as a jock.

Comment: Voting to reopen because "gentleman jockey" is not the sum of its parts.  In fact it means the opposite of what you would assume if you looked up each part and pieced it together.

Comment: OP, who is an experienced user with 11000+ reputation at Stack.Overflow, seems to have Googled the whole sentence "gentleman jockey wins derby" which does not yield any illuminating result with or without quotes,  mainly because it is a sentence from fiction and apparently not a common statement in general English. Googling the term "gentleman jockey" gives the proper definition as the very first entry. My only confusion and question to OP would be, why did you GOOGLE "gentleman jockey wins derby" and not just "gentleman jockey"? I appreciate the efforts of all the members who reopened this Q.

Comment: Why did I mention that OP is an *experienced user with 11000+ reputation at StackOverflow?* Because it shows that OP is least likely to ask a question on any StackExchange site without doing the basic research! Or does that rule apply only to ELU? With due respect to all concerned, every question that needs to be reopened (without having had to make substantial edits to bring it 'on topic') **should be** considered a question that was *closed hastily in the first place*, or 'laboring under some misconception.' So pease don't vote to close any question unless you are **certain** it's off-topic!

Comment: @EnglishStudent It's not always "closed" as off-topic. It's initially "put on hold", which technically is "closed", but in a sense that we are waiting for the OP to edit additional info into the question before welcoming any new answers.

Comment: @NVZ thank you for the clarification. I understand this is a good process to ensure quality, but feel that it is often applied arbitrarily. While the questions that are put on hold usually deserve to be, a number of other such Q remain open. Meanwhile a great deal of energy is spent reopening a closed question... I am aware that the huge volume of queries is a challenge for senior members and moderators, and *appreciate your efforts on our behalf*. I shall try to prepare a more detailed and useful question regarding this matter on ***meta.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Gentleman Jockey](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-Gentleman%20Jockey)*** is an expression that refers to:

> - Amateur rider, generally in steeplechases.

By extension it is used to refer to someone who is not a professional  player but may happen to be a winner despite their inexperience.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I certainly googled before asking here. But I got no results for the whole phrase and didn't think of asking for part of the phrase.

Comment: @Maximus - you are welcome, preliminary research is considered essential in this site, so next time please remember to mention it.

Comment: will do, good luck)

Comment: In this case Gentleman also implies upper class  as used to happen in cricket

Answer (score 3):

The term ***gentleman jockey*** can be used as a derogatory term for a member of the upper class dabbling in the sport - a dilettante with no real skills.

An excellent description can be found in the January 1848 issue of *The Sportsman*:

> Critics will tell us that at the amateur performance, Mr. So-and-so,
> or Lord Such-a-one, played *Charles Surface* or *Sir George Airy*,
> very well--for a gentleman. Even in our own line, where a gentleman is
> declared to be nothing and nobody without his recreations, he still
> plays but second ﬁddle at them. A gentleman huntsman, nine times in
> ten, is taken but as another term for a bad one; and a gentleman
> jockey generally unites the two on much the same understanding. At
> most he may reach in this sphere the acme allowed by Mr. Scrope
> Davies, who, in speaking of a friend’s great efforts to carry out the
> character in every perticular, admitted “he did look and ride like a
> jockey, but then it was like a *bad* jockey."
>
> [The Sportsman, January 1848, p. 343](https://books.google.com/books?id=sCsGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA343&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false)

---

I could not find any occurrences of the phrase ***gentleman jockey wins the Derby*** other than the dialog mentioned in the OP. But based on the above I would interpret it as an affirmation and rephrase of the preceding sentence:

> 01:14:56 I'm just an amateur.
> 01:14:59 Beginner's luck, huh?
> 01:15:02 Gentleman jockey wins the Derby.
> 01:15:05 Something like that.
> [link](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M14924e4ff/The+Thomas+Crown+Affair/Gentleman+jockey+wins+the+Derby)

In other words, my success is due to an unlikely stroke of luck, similar to an amateur (an inept one) winning a professional competition.